# Monkey patching a function

Tags: elisp, functions, advice

Some context:

I'm doing some linux kernel development on a Debian VM so naturally I'm using tramp. I want to use semantic-symref, but the trouble is that:

1. Semantic will eventually call `cedet-gnu-global-call`
2. Which will use the value of `cedet-global-command`
3. Which will crap out because it uses 'call-process.

So from what I understand, I need it to be using `tramp-call-process`.

My question is, can I monkey patch a function, namely `cedet-gnu-global-call`? I have seen stuff like `defadvice`, is this a use case for my problem?

By monkey patching, I mean that I want to replace `cedet-gnu-global-call` with mine, but at runtime.

Or is there some way to get `cedet-global to be smart` when used over tramp?

Comment: Actually, rather than `tramp-call-process`, it should probably call `process-file` (which does delegate to Tramp, depending on default-directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emacs ≥24.4, you could try something like

```
(defun my-call-process-hack (orig program &rest args)
  (apply (if (equal program cedet-global-command) #'process-file orig)
         program args))
(advice-add 'call-process :around #'my-call-process-hack)
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked. Now I just have a problem of semantic-symref giving me an empty buffer for results, even for kmalloc.., but at least this problem is solved.

Comment: Alternative to `semantic-symref`, you could use `ggtags-find-references` from [ggtags](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags). I wrote a guide for using it [here](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#sec-1). If you want `semantic-symref` to be functional, you have to setup include paths with EDE.

Comment: @TuDo I will check out `ggtags-find-references`. I basically avoid EDE and got semantic working on mostly everything by manually setting up the `semantic-dependency-*` functions. Also, your posts are absolutely incredible! Thank you so much for them. EDIT: ggtags-find-references works! Excellent!